# Perl datetime generated?

Tags: perl, datetime

I have a perl script that takes system date and write that date to a filename.

System date is assigned to TRH1 variable and then it set to a filename.

```
$TRH1 =`date + %Y%m%d%H%M`;
print "TRH1 => $TRH1\n";
open(TPFILE, ">./log/errTS_TPList_$TRH1.csv");
```

However, TRH1 seems to have correct value but file name has a question mark, that I do not desire.

```
TRH1 => 202103031940
errTS_TPList_202103031940?.csv
```

Can you show me how to get rid of this "?" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute the shell command, you need to `chomp` it.

Also use a modern way to write into a file, using a lexical filehandle.

Try in this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict; use warnings;

my $TRH1 = `date +%Y%m%d%H%M`;
chomp $TRH1;

print "TRH1 => $TRH1\n";

my $filename = "log/errTS_TPList_$TRH1.csv";
open(my $TPFILE, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename'";
```

Answer (score 5):

As you've [already been shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66470325/7231), it's because the output from `date` has a newline character at the end that you need to remove with `chomp()`.

However, there's really no need to use an external program to get the date and time. Modern versions of Perl come with [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) which makes this trivial:

```
use Time::Piece;

# Perl style generally reserves uppercase variable names
# for constants
my $trh1 = localtime->strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M");
```

With an older version of Perl, you can use `strftime()` from [POSIX](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/ext/POSIX/lib/POSIX.pod):

```
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $trh1 = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M", localtime);
```

Comment: Re "*With an older version of Perl*", With any version of Perl

Comment: @ikegami: True :-)